# Reading multiple RSS feeds with MVC & Linq to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-xml

I am really rusty when it comes to coding and have been working hard to find the answer but am at my whits end right now.

My website has a database of stored RSS URLs. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to loop through and display all of the RSS feeds data.

I can get one feed to show just fine, but displaying all of them, I just don't know what to do to get them all to display. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Model:** RSS.cs

```
namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    public class RSS
    {
        public string Link    { get; set; }
        public string Title         { get; set; }
        public string Description   { get; set; }
        public string PubDate       { get; set; }
        public string Date          { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model:** RSSReader.cs

```
namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    public class RSSReader
    {
        private static string _URL = "";

        public static IEnumerable<RSS> GetRSSFeed()
        {
            IEnumerable<RSS> feeds = null;
            XDocument feedXml = null;
            XNamespace rss = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/";
            XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var url in BansheeData.GetURL(count))
            {
                _URL = url.url1;
                feedXml = XDocument.Load(_URL);

                    feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants(rss + "item")
                            select new RSS
                            {
                                Title = feed.Element(rss + "title").Value,
                                Link = feed.Element(rss + "link").Value,
                                Date = feed.Element(dc + "date").Value.Remove(10)
                            };

                count++;
            }

            return feeds;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:** RSSController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      var urlFeed = MyWebsite.Models.RSSReader.GetRSSFeed();
      return View(urlFeed);
}
```

**View:** _RSSFeed.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyWebsite.Models.RSS>

@foreach (var item in Model) { 
    <section>
        <header class="overflow">
            <h1>
                <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank" class="alt overflow">
                    <span class="fl">@Html.Raw(item.Title)</span>
                    <span class="ref fr">Source, @Html.Encode(item.Date)</span>
                </a>
            </h1>
        </header>
    </section>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a problem in your code. You are missing to add items into the list for each iteration.

So instead of:

```
            foreach (var url in BansheeData.GetURL(count))
            {
                _URL = url.url1;
                feedXml = XDocument.Load(_URL);

                feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants(rss + "item")
                            select new RSS
                            {
                                Title = feed.Element(rss + "title").Value,
                                Link = feed.Element(rss + "link").Value,
                                Date = feed.Element(dc + "date").Value.Remove(10)
                            };

                count++;
            }

            return feeds;
```

You try do `AddRange` into the list for each iteration:

```
        var rssList = new List<RSS>;

        foreach (var url in BansheeData.GetURL(count))
        {
            _URL = url.url1;
            feedXml = XDocument.Load(_URL);

            feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants(rss + "item")
                        select new RSS
                        {
                            Title = feed.Element(rss + "title").Value,
                            Link = feed.Element(rss + "link").Value,
                            Date = feed.Element(dc + "date").Value.Remove(10)
                        };

            rssList.AddRange(feeds);

            count++;
        }

        return rssList;
```

This should help. Now you should got the whole list of the RSS. The core logic is when you iterate and you get item(s) that you need in each iteration cycle you should remember them. That means save them in a temp list.